# Network Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Our Electrical Engineering professor told us about this formula relating to circuits:

$$Network \ Theorem: \  \ \ \
b = m+n-1$$

where $b$ = number of branches in  circuit, $m$ = number of closed loops, $n$ = number of nodes

Does anyone know what this formula is actually called? I wanted to check out the proof, but I couldn't find anything about it from Google.

Comment: What is a branch?

Comment: Okay, after some digging trying to find out what a branch is, I came across the same law.  It is also known as the Fundamental Theorem of Network Topology.  You might be able to find a proof for it under that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euler's formula for Planar graphs, I think. 
EDIT: To clarify further, here m (nbr of loops) corresponds to (number of faces - 1), since we do not count the infinite face bounded outside the circuit.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but that formula is $v − e + f = 2.$

Comment: yeah, but in this context m = f-1, i think.

Comment: Ah! Okay.  You wouldn't count the outer face, I guess.  So branches would be what graph theorists typically call edges, then?

Comment: Yes, branches are edges. And they are non-intersecting.

Comment: @vben: You are completely correct on the 'not counting outer face' argument.